# How to appropriately set passenger_base_uri in standalone mode

Tags: passenger

I am currently trying to determine how to appropriately set passenger_base_uri when running passenger in standalone mode. I tried overriding the nginx.conf.erb to include passenger_base_uri, I also tried setting the location block as specified on
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-sub-uri
Both of those methods produced the strange result of randomly serving 404s.

Was curious if there was a straightforward way to configure this for a single app (it looks like there might have been a environment variable option to allow this at some point?).

I'm not trying to deploy multiple apps on a single passenger server, just trying to change the context of a single app without having to alter routes.

Versions from passenger-status:
nginx/1.12.2 Phusion_Passenger/5.2.3

Update:
I tried on the latest version of passenger (6.0.1) and still see random 404s. I also tried upping the logging level on passenger and it appears that there is an issue where some of the passenger processes aren't appropriately setting "SCRIPT_NAME" before passing the request through. I can't seem to reproduce this error locally, but can reliably reproduce it in a deployed instance.

Same pid serving both 404s and 200s:

```
# passenger-status && curl -I -k https://127.0.0.1/test/meta/availability
Version : 6.0.1
Date    : 2019-01-23 00:31:59 +0000
Instance: 36X3YTqe (nginx/1.15.8 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.1)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 10
App groups    : 1
Processes     : 10
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/opt/app (production):
  App root: /opt/app
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 129     Sessions: 0       Processed: 59      Uptime: 12m 55s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 68M     Last used: 1s ago
  * PID: 152     Sessions: 0       Processed: 1       Uptime: 12m 54s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 45M     Last used: 12m 54s ago
  * PID: 176     Sessions: 0       Processed: 0       Uptime: 12m 54s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 41M     Last used: 12m 54s ago
  * PID: 202     Sessions: 0       Processed: 0       Uptime: 12m 53s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 41M     Last used: 12m 53s ago
....

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 23 Jan 2019 00:32:00 GMT
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 6.0.1
Server: nginx/1.15.8 + Phusion Passenger 6.0.1
```

```
# passenger-status && curl -I -k https://127.0.0.1/test/meta/availability
Version : 6.0.1
Date    : 2019-01-23 00:32:01 +0000
Instance: 36X3YTqe (nginx/1.15.8 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.1)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 10
App groups    : 1
Processes     : 10
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/opt/app (production):
  App root: /opt/app
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 129     Sessions: 0       Processed: 60      Uptime: 12m 57s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 68M     Last used: 1s ago
  * PID: 152     Sessions: 0       Processed: 1       Uptime: 12m 56s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 45M     Last used: 12m 56s ago
  * PID: 176     Sessions: 0       Processed: 0       Uptime: 12m 56s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 41M     Last used: 12m 56s ago
  * PID: 202     Sessions: 0       Processed: 0       Uptime: 12m 55s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 41M     Last used: 12m 55s ago
....

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 23 Jan 2019 00:32:01 GMT
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 6.0.1
Server: nginx/1.15.8 + Phusion Passenger 6.0.1
```

Comment: Interestingly overriding the whole nginx conf with what was generated using the erb and adding the base_uri setting to the existing location blocks seems to get rid of the 404s

Comment: Do you mean you copied the default nginx conf file into the root of the rails app and add the passenger_base_uri value in that file? If not, please share where you did the overriding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some feedback on a similar sounding [github issue](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2117). Looks to be an issue with newer versions of passenger (greater than 5.1, current highest available is 6.0.1). It should be possible to just set passenger_base_uri, but the bug causes the random 404s.